# R formula syntax

Tags: r, function

I'm training a neural network with a large dataset and need to specify the formula.
data$X is a 5000x400 matrix with the training data (real numbers), data$y is a 5000x1 matrix with the corresponding output (0-9).

```
data$y ~ data$X[,1]+data$X[,2]+ ... + data$X[,400]
```

How can I achieve this without writing it by hand for all 400 rows?

```
data$y ~ .
```

does not work.

this works (nnet package):

```
net2 <- nnet(data$y ~ data$X[,1]+data$X[,2], size=10, threshold=0.01)
```

or this (neuralnet package):

```
net <- neuralnet(data$y ~ data$X[,1]+data$X[,2], hidden=10, threshold=0.01)
```

but I want it for data$y ~ data$X[,1] + data$X[,2] + ... + data$X[,400]

```
> str(data)
List of 2
 $ X: num [1:5000, 1:400] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ y: num [1:5000, 1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 - attr(*, "header")=List of 3
 ..$ description: chr "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Sun Oct 16     13:09:09 2011                                                "
 ..$ version    : chr "5"
 ..$ endian     : chr "little"
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using `nnet` package, this should work

```
library(nnet)
nnet(y~.,data=data,...)
```

Or the the other form:

```
nnet(x= subset(data,select=-y), y = data$y,...)
```

Comment: > nnet(x=data$X, y=data$y,size=10, threshold=0.01)
Fehler in nnet.default(x = data$X, y = data$y, size = 10, threshold = 0.01) : 
  zu viele (4021) Gewichte

Comment: then I get this error:  > nnet(y ~., data=data, size=10, threshold=0.01)
error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X.1' not found

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
dat2 <- cbind(data$X,data$y)

nnet(dat2[,401] ~., data=dat2, size=2, threshold= 0.01)
```